# Visual Studio Hardware Recommendations

Tags: hard-drive, memory, cpu, visual-studio

I am currently arguing for better hardware for our development machines.  We exclusively use the Microsoft stack, running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and TFS 2012 Update 4, with SQL 2008R2.  Our machines (laptops) definitely meet the "requirements":

- 8GB RAM
- AMD Quad Core processor
- 7200 RPM Drive with plenty of space
- Integrated graphics with DirectX 11

However, we are all experiencing issues when loading not only our solutions, but Visual Studio itself.  We are pretty sure this is a result of the hard drive and processor (it does not benchmark very well, but CPU Boss says it's fine).  We are currently lobbying for a newer processor, and an SSD, but are getting some push back, specifically on the SSD.

A few years back, I found a [blog post from Brian Harry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/your-visual-studio-2010-dream-machine/) about the ideal machine setup for Visual Studio 2010.  However, being 5 years old it is only marginally useful today.

Have there been any such recommendations from Microsoft about Visual Studio 2015 (or 2013)?

Comment: A faster CPU will decrease compile times.  Of course compile times are dependent on the size of the project in the first place.  With respect to a SSD, compiling a project and loading a project will both be faster by several factors.  As for the recommended hardware since those recommendations are just for the Visual Studio itself and has nothing to do with project that might be loaded.  Recommendation for faster compile times have not changed in 5 years, you are going to want fast multiple core processors, as much memory as you can get, and use the fastest storage devices possible.

Comment: @Ramhound Right.  We know that it will improve our situation, but it can be difficult to convince the people that need to pay for such things, when only the devlopers notice an issue.

Comment: If management does not take the word of their developers why would they trust the recommendation of random people?  If you sit around waiting on your machine to finish compiling a project for an hour a day, and you can prove a new machine would decrease that to 5 minutes a day, management will do something to make that happen.  How you prove how much a performance increase you will get is up to you to accomplish, you don't have to provide specifics, you can estimate based on the speed of a SSD or faster processor.  33% write performance would mean a file is created that much faster.

Comment: disable the HW acceleration inside the VS options

Answer (score 1):

Your system specs far exceed Microsoft's basic requirements:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#2

So using a publication, professional or otherwise, to justify increasing your specs above and beyond might not be the best approach.  Given the recommended specs as compares to yours, I would be (as a manager) dubious about going up another notch.

You're going to need to find some way to identify the actual problem - is it a hardware issue or is there something about the way the solution is built that is causing it to take so long?

If I were your manager and you came to me with this request, I would want some clear evidence that the hardware is the problem and also that you had done thorough due diligence to exclude the project solution as the problem.

Comment: You're right @DaveJohnson - changed my wording.  Even so - several times the minimum required memory should be better than sufficient.